# Why did apple use (mach_header 's pointer subtract `__TEXT` 's vmaddr) to calculate slide value of ASLR

Tags: c, dyld, mach-o, aslr

It is really confused me a lot! When I read apple open source code of [getsecbyname.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-698/dyld/getsecbyname.c.auto.html). Some code In it:

```
uint8_t * 
getsectiondata(
const struct mach_header *mhp,
const char *segname,
const char *sectname,
unsigned long *size) {
    slide = 0;
    sp = 0;
    sgp = (struct segment_command *)
          ((char *)mhp + sizeof(struct mach_header));
    for(i = 0; i < mhp->ncmds; i++){
        if(sgp->cmd == LC_SEGMENT){
        if(strcmp(sgp->segname, "__TEXT") == 0){
            slide = (uintptr_t)mhp - sgp->vmaddr;
        }
    ......
}
```

I can understand what is ASLR(Address Space Layout Random). And I also know that slide's value should be equal to loader address subtract linker address: `slide = L(loader address) - A(linker address)`. But why slide value in here which is `slide = (uintptr_t)mhp - sgp->vmaddr;`. Does that mean `mhp`(mach_header) is the loader address? I can constrainedly recognize "__TEXT"'s vmaddr is the linker address because which is read from the load command. But why the mach_header address become the loader address in here, which should be always 0x00000000 in my opinion.

And I have roughly read the source code of [xnu](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu) of Apple. I read function `load_machfile` and function `parse_machfile` consisted in `xnu` source  earnestly. However, I'm more confused now. I really appreciate if someone can help me!

Answer (score 3):

By necessity, the Mach-O header is at file offset 0 (otherwise it wouldn't be a header). And by convention, the __TEXT segment maps the content at file offset 0. So the address of the Mach-O header and that of the __TEXT segment are one and the same.

Now you just have to get the link-time value and the runtime value of that address, subtract one from the other and you have the slide. The value in `sgp->vmaddr` is the link-time one, because the Mach-O header is not modified during load (and it will usually be `0x100000000` for standalone executables if you didn't pass any custom linker options). Meanwhile, `mhp` is a live pointer so it is the same value, but with the slide applied.

Comment: Appreciate first. Then the followings:
 1. `mhp` is a pointer belong to vm system that stored in kernel memory areas. Therefore, loader apply a slide value to it. And the layout of vm logical struct should be:

```
    .....slide...
    _________
    mhp struct 
    _________
    __TEXT
    _________
    __DATA
    _________
      ..........
```


2. `mhp` is a copy of Mach-O header from binary executable file that stored on disks.

Are these right ?

Comment: @Bernard I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Thanks anyway, @Siguza. Ignore the previous comment. And I really understand the reason. I misunderstand the map process of the Mach-O file. I always thought the Mach-O  header and __TEXT segment are two separate areas and the __TEXT segment must start with __TEXT, __text section in VM. In fact, it's not. Since I neglected the file offset value which indicates the offset in this file of the data to be mapped at `vmaddr`.